# Pipe texture size in flappy bird game

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new to android development and I am trying to create the flappy bird game using LibGDX. When I am inserting the pipes I am getting some empty space as seen in the image below. How can I fix it?

[image: pipeImage]

```
    batch.draw(tTube, tubeX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + gap / 2 + tubeOffset);
    batch.draw(bTube, tubeX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - gap / 2 - bTube.getHeight() + tubeOffset);
```

Thank you

Comment: You should provide some code snippets to make it more clear how you made that. I assume you've created a Texture instance of that pipe image and drew with a sprite batch. If so, then draw the pipe with a higher Y value:
batch.draw(pipeTexture, x, <y_higher_value>);

Comment: I added the code

Comment: For the top tube you can do:
batch.draw(tTube, tubeX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - tubeHeight);
This will draw the tube attached with its top border to the screen top border

Comment: It didn't worked and I am getting the same problem in the bottom tube also.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it longer.

If the gap is at the very bottom and you're drawing the top tube `height` at `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2` or less the top tube won't reach the top of the screen. But if you make sure the tubes are `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` then the tube will always reach the top.

```
Vector2 tubeSize;
float gapPos;

public void create(){
   ...
   ...

   tubeSize = Scaling.fillY.apply(tTube.getWidth(),tTube.getHeight(),0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
   //Make the gap size 20% of the screen height, or edit as you like
   gapSize = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.20f;
   // Make a random gap position on the y axis
   gapPos = MathUtils.random(gapSize,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-gapSize); 
}

public void render(){
   ...
   ...

   batch.begin();
   batch.draw(tTube, tubeX, gapPos + gapSize/2,tubeSize.x,tubeSize.y);
   batch.draw(bTube, tubeX, gapPos - gapSize/2 - tubeSize.y,tubeSize.x,tubeSize.y);
   batch.end();
}
```

This, of course, will make the tubes look bigger, but if you edit the png file and make the tubes longer you should archive the desired result.

[image]

**With a longer tube...**

[image]